# Property/Method Descriptions for COM Libraries

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vb6-migration, regasm

If you create a COMClass, I've noticed that the values in the XML Summary tag do not show in the object browser of VB6/VBA when you reference the resulting tlb file. Is there a way to have these values show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, 12 years of IntelliSense evolution prevents this from working.  The XML documentation comments generates an .xml file that IntelliSense can pick up.

In VB6/A, documentation is present in the type library with the `helpstring` attribute.  For example:

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(2334D2B1-713E-11CF-8AE5-00AA00C00905),
  hidden,
  dual,
  nonextensible,
  oleautomation
]
interface IVBDataObject : IDispatch {
    [id(0x00000001), helpstring("Clears all data and formats in a DataObject object."), helpcontext(0x00033693)]
    HRESULT Clear();
    // etc...
};
```

Getting the same from your `[ComVisible]` class library requires the `[Description]` attribute.  Note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6668837/17034) for a quirk about the way it works for properties.

Comment: Well that's bad news, but I'd upvote it twice if I could for the work-around. Thanks again.