# Getting the helpstring attribute applied to C# properties exposed via COM interfaces

Tags: c#, com, interface, properties, interop

I'm currently working on a library that's to be exposed to COM for use in a legacy project that's being upgraded. I'm creating interfaces that are to be exposed, and they have properties on them with long, int, etc types.  Using the DescriptionAttribute, I can get helpstrings generated in the .tlb for interfaces, classes, and methods, but for some reason it doesn't seem to want to work for properties.  Is there anyway to get a helpstring generated in the TLB output for properties ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to put the attribute on the getter and setter individually.  Like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    [ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IFoo {
        int property {
            [Description("prop")]
            get;
            [Description("prop")]
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Repeating the description is clumsy, but also required in IDL.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  Is there any way to do the same thing with method parameters ? I can't get those to work either.  For methods themselves, it's fine, but not the parameters, or return values.

Comment: No, not supported by type libraries.

Comment: I know this is noise, but I *needed* to thank you @HansPassant. Every time I have a question about COM, there you are with an answer.